# How can I integrate tkinterdnd2 into my existing tkinter window, without creating a new window

Tags: python, tkinter

I am playing around with the functionality of `tkinterdnd2`. Hereby I created a `Listbox` for simple drag&drop action. I am looking for a solution to integrate `tkinterdnd2` function `drop_target_register`, without replacing `tk.Frame` with `TkinterDnD.Tk`. How can I create a class instance of `TkinterDnD`, without creating a new window? Basically I just want give my listbox the drag&drop functionality.

```
class App(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    

        frame = tk.Frame(self)
        frame.pack(expand=tk.YES, fill=tk.BOTH)

        self.file_names_listbox = tk.Listbox(frame, selectmode=tk.SINGLE, background="darkgray", height=  100, width=100)
        self.file_names_listbox.pack()
        self.file_names_listbox.drop_target_register(DND_ALL)
        self.file_names_listbox.dnd_bind("<<Drop>>", self.say_hello)


    def say_hello(self, event):
        print("It works")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
```

When I am replacing `tk.Frame` with `TkinterDnD.Tk` the code runs perfectly.

Thank you for your help.

I basicaly wanted to create a drag&drop listbox, but unfortunately I have create a window which inherits from the `TkinterDnD` class.

Comment: If using `TkinterDnD.Tk` works, why don't use it? Do you mean that you already have an instance of `Tk()`, so you don't want to create another instance of `TkinterDnD.Tk()`?

Comment: Because I want to integrate these few line of code to a bigger project.  There I am having multiple files and classes. For my multiple frame setup I have to use a class which inherits from tk.frame. Everthing should be in one window, When I am using TkinterDnD.tk for my mainclass I am not able to switch between my frames. Therefore I am looking for a solution to integrate TkinterDnD only to the widget

Comment: Try `from tkinterdnd2.TkinterDnD import _require` then add `_require(self)` after `super().__init__()` inside `App.__init__()`.

Comment: `'class App(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
       
        App.__init__( _require(self))`  #If you mean it like this, it didn´t work

Comment: No just `_require(self)`, not `App.__init__(_require(self))`.

Comment: the code runs wihtout any error. Now the window opens, but it hasn´t any drag&drop function. So the `drop_target_register` function does´t work

Comment: It is because instance of `App` is invisible because you haven't called any layout function on it.  Add `app.pack()` after `app = App()`.